# Upstart service in start/killed state

Tags: bash, ubuntu, service, upstart, init.d

I have a python application that needs to run as a service on Ubuntu 14.04. This application needs to have the following capabilities:

1. When then service is started, a cron entry is created in the crontab, which will periodically run the application.
2. When the service is stopped, the crontab entry is removed.
3. When the system/server is rebooted, the service needs to be started.

I have the following upstart script to run my service:

```
start on [2345]
stop on [!2345]

script
    LOGDIR=/usr/local/etc/myservice/logs/
    CFGFILE=/usr/local/etc/myservice/myservice.conf

    echo $$ > /var/run/myservice.pid
    # If there is no cronjob by the name myservice, then add a cronjob to the crontab
    set -x
    exec bash -c '
    if (( $(crontab -l | grep -c myservice) == 0 )); then
       (crontab -l ; echo "1 * * * * myservice) | crontab -
    fi'
end script

pre-start script
    set -x
    echo "[`date`] Starting myservice Service" >> /var/log/myservice.log

    # Testing to see if myservice has been installed, else exit
    [ -x /usr/local/bin/myservice ] || exit 0
    mkdir -p /usr/local/etc/myservice/logs/
end script

pre-stop script
    set -x
    echo "[`date`] Stopping myservice Service" >> /var/log/myservice.log
end script

post-stop script
    set -x
    rm /var/run/myservice.pid
    # If there is at least 1 cronjob by the name myservice, remove all such entries from crontab
    exec bash -c '
    if (( $(crontab -l | grep -c myservice) >= 0 )); then
       (crontab -l | grep -v myservice) | crontab -
    fi'
    pkill -f myservice
end script
```

However, when I try to run the service, it hangs and I have to hit ctrl+c to get back the command line. Similarly with the stopping of the service. Am I missing something here? Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Nevermind guys! I managed to fix the issue myself ....

Comment: Please post an answer summarizing what your solution was (even if it was simple or obvious). It may help others in the future.